# Can I put a potion in an alchemical capsule?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, equipment, potions

Complete Adventurer has rules for small alchemical capsules that hold "small amount of an alchemical substance" or "one dose of any contact poison or ingested poison". Does this mean they could also be used to hold a single potion?

Comment: What makes you think they do? The text certainly doesn't seem to suggest that.

Comment: @Erik It's mostly that they can contain 1 dose of posion. I'm not sure how big a "dose" is, but potions themselves aren't exactly huge at 1 ounce

Comment: Is there a goal or is this curiosity? I mean, there are other ways to quickly coat a weapon with a magical oil. (Coating a weapon with a *potion* wouldn't do much anyway!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Main purpose is to find an item to let someone covertly and quickly consume a potion

Comment: How about posing *that* question?

Answer (score 4):

Potions, poisons, and alchemical items are three separate categories. Nothing that applies to one automatically applies to any of the others. If the alchemical capsule was supposed to work with potions, potions would be listed.

*Why* they should work with alchemy or poisons, but not potions, is entirely unaddressed by the description. It might be that a dose of poison or alchemy is simply smaller than a dose of potion. Or perhaps something about them interferes with magic—alchemical items and poisons are typically not magical (though the fact that the alchemical capsules don’t interfere with the alchemy or poisons that *are* magical suggests this isn’t the answer). But maybe it’s the particular way in which magic is suspended in liquid for potions, that isn’t true of alchemy or poisons made from liquids that are themselves magical. Or something else entirely. Wizards of the Coast decided not to include that detail. That leaves it up to the DM to decide. And maybe he decides there is no good reason it shouldn’t work, and allows potions as a houserule.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say no. Potions have a large enough volume to be drunk. The 10 drops that fits in a capsule doesn't really feel like a potion.

At the end of the day, its a dm call, but it doesn't really feel right.